# Permanent magnet in ac motor

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor, electromagnetic, magnet

Is Magnet in pmac motor degrade while they are in use because in tesla model 3 they uses pmac motor so we have to replace magnet frequently ?

Comment: The magnets should last for the life of the car. Bearings will wear out before magnets.

Comment: So magnets energy doesn't get used when in use

Comment: Energy is not used. Maybe magnets can wear out after a long time. But they are not the failure point in a permanent magnet motor (unless they are allowed to get very hot).

Comment: at which condition they wear out ?

Comment: on other questions answer people say magnet lose energy

Comment: Can you please provide some links?

Comment: These are the links https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8036/do-magnets-lose-their-magnetism   https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14667/how-long-does-a-permanent-magnet-remain-a-magnet

Comment: OK, I read those answers. Nobody in those answers seems to know how long it may take. But as I said before, over normal engineering time frames, I don't think you need to worry about it. I have speakers that are 50 years old, and still seem to work. I have never heard of a BLDC motor wearing out because the magnets in the rotor lost their magnetism. On the other hand, maybe in 1000 years or 100,000 years, magnets will wear out. But your car will not last that long, so it should not be a concern.

Comment: so if we build magnet motor with only using magnet then it should run for 1000 years

Comment: You can't build a motor using only magnets.

Comment: Think if its working then how long it will last

Comment: please reply fast

Comment: Sorry. It makes no sense. You cannot build a motor with only magnets.

Answer (score 3):

In a properly designed motor, no, they will not degrade. This sort of thing was a problem with older permanent magnet materials (if you are old enough you might remember the need for 'keeper iron' on the magnets at school) but with modern rare-earth magnets this is not a problem.

A permanent magnet is essentially a magnetic material with an extremely large B-H curve hysteresis. When you apply a large magneto-motive force (MMF) across the material, the magnet retains most of this force when it is removed. To demagnetize the magnet, or reverse the polarity, you have to supply a sufficiently large MMF in the opposing direction to 'snap over' to the other side of the hysteresis curve. In old magnetic materials, even the reluctance generated by the airgap between the poles could be sufficient to do this (hence the need for keeper iron), but with new materials the required MMF is so large that specialist magnetizing equipment is typically required.

If the motor is poorly designed, then it is possible that under transient conditions this could occur, but in most motor typologies the backing iron will saturate long before a sufficient field can be generated to demagnetize the permanent magnets. However, at a critical temperature permanent magnetization can be lost in most permanent magnet materials, so this remains a real risk if internal temperatures are not carefully managed.

Comment: if i build motor with only magnet then how long it will last(just  thought experiment)

Answer (score 1):

Permanent magnets don't degrade in use. They can fail if things go wrong and their vulnerabilities differ from other types of motors, but that doesn't mean that they are inherently more prone to failure.

Comment: so repel force on magnet doesn't degrade magnet . Because when motor regen it becomes a generator.

Comment: No. Permanent magnets are also used for generators. A motor acting as a generator during regenerative braking is no different than a generator in a wind turbine.

Comment: if we imagine magnet motor with only using magnet then how long it will last

Comment: A motor is defined as a mechanism that causes an action by converting a flow of input energy into sustained motion. At minimum, magnet must have input energy from a magnetic field created by a electric current in a conductor to sustain motion. You could think of a magnetic cabinet  door latch as a motor that pulls and holds the door when it is closed. Those last for many years. You could probably find one that has been is daily use for 50 years.

Comment: but some how its working then how long it will last

Comment: Imagining a perpetual motion machine composed of magnets is equivalent to imagining a collection of magnets on a storage shelf.  Alnico magnets have been around for about 75 years with early examples showing no loss of strength. Earlier permanent magnets were used for compasses, galvanometers, D’Arsonval meters. Many examples can be found in working order after 100 years or longer. A permanent magnet is permanent unless it is damaged by some accident or intentional act. Don't beat a dead horse.